# Explicitly Permit Access to /error (Spring Boot 2.7.x / Spring Security 5.7.x)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Is it normally required to explicitly permit a Spring Boot application to have access to `/error` (and in our case `/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp`)?  Here's our working security configuration (Spring Boot 2.7.2; Spring Security 5.7.2):

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/public/**", "/assets/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
  .antMatchers("/super/**").hasAuthority(UserRole.SUPER.name())
  
  .antMatchers("/**/*error*").authenticated() // <!-- FIX ALLOWING ACCESS TO ERROR PAGE ON 403
  
  .anyRequest().hasAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
  .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
  .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll();

  return http.build();
}
```

Without this, requests to restricted content by non-admin users results in a blank page.

We've been using Spring (Boot/Security) for a while and I don't recall having to include this fix before now.  Are we doing something wrong?

**Update**
This may have to do with running as .war on existing Tomcat server versus running on embedded Tomcat server.  Running on (non-embedded) Tomcat server access to `/error` works without issue, however when running with embedded Tomcat, the above explicit configuration appears to be required.